# does InAppWebView has method like onPageFinished?

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

Does InAppWebview in flutter has method like onPageFinished like native Android? I have Implemented onLoadStop, onConsoleMessage, shouldOverrideUrlLoading but none give me the expected output.
I went through the documentation for InAppWebview but there is no such method.

How do I achieve this in flutter. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_inappwebview/latest/flutter_inappwebview/WebView/onLoadStop.html) is the only method available and it does actually call by method channel the Android native `onPageFinished()`. It gives me the expected behavior. It would be fired as soon as the webview finishes loading the Url. One can get the available properties and methods from the webview's attached controller which is passed as an argument in the `onLoadStop` method call.